Como fazer um select dentro de outro select com uma condição no mysql
Possuo duas tabelas fullfillment_produtos e fullfillment_produtos_itens, como faço para selecionar apenas os registros na tabela fullfillment_produtos se houver um registro ou mais vinculado ao id dela na tabela fullfillment_produtos_itens. Acredito que seria usando uma sub consulta, mas nunca fiz isso.
SELECT id, codigo_mlb, permalink, titulo, com_variacao, data_cadastro  
            FROM tb_fullfillment_produtos produto 
            WHERE 
            seller_id = {$this->sellerID} 
            ORDER BY qtd_vendido DESC

Como posso fazer essa subconsulta dentro dessa já existente?

Se entendi o problema pesquise por EXISTS. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

não bastaria fazer um inner join? isso vai te trazer só os registros que tem correspondentes na 2a tabela

Importante você [edit] sua pergunta convertendo o código em um [mcve] do problema, explicar como tentou resolver e descrever o mais objetivamente possível qual foi a dificuldade encontrada. Ao editar, automaticamente sua pergunta é destacada para uma revisão e a comunidade reavalia os votos e o fechamento. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site.

Então, pelo que você explicou, acho que dá pra resolver isso de duas formas: usando um EXISTS ou um INNER JOIN. Vou tentar explicar de um jeito simples pra vc pegar rápido.
Usando EXISTS:
O EXISTS é uma boa pq ele só verifica se existe algum registro na outra tabela relacionado ao id da tabela principal. Fica assim:
SELECT id, codigo_mlb, permalink, titulo, com_variacao, data_cadastro  
FROM tb_fullfillment_produtos produto
WHERE seller_id = {$this->sellerID}
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM tb_fullfillment_produtos_itens item
    WHERE item.id_produto = produto.id
)
ORDER BY qtd_vendido DESC;

Aqui, o EXISTS vai retornar true se encontrar pelo menos um registro em tb_fullfillment_produtos_itens com o mesmo id_produto que está na tabela tb_fullfillment_produtos. O SELECT 1 dentro do EXISTS é só pra dizer "ei, verifica se existe algo", então não precisa de mais dados.

Usando INNER JOIN:
Se vc quiser fazer um join, ele tbm resolve. A ideia é só trazer os registros de tb_fullfillment_produtos que têm correspondência na outra tabela:
SELECT DISTINCT produto.id, produto.codigo_mlb, produto.permalink, 
                produto.titulo, produto.com_variacao, produto.data_cadastro
FROM tb_fullfillment_produtos produto
INNER JOIN tb_fullfillment_produtos_itens item
ON produto.id = item.id_produto
WHERE produto.seller_id = {$this->sellerID}
ORDER BY produto.qtd_vendido DESC;

O INNER JOIN só vai trazer os registros que têm um match entre produto.id e item.id_produto. Coloquei DISTINCT pq dependendo do relacionamento (1 pra N), pode repetir as linhas se houver mais de um item vinculado.

Qual usar?

EXISTS: mais simples se vc só quer verificar se existem registros na outra tabela.
INNER JOIN: útil se vc precisar trazer mais infos da outra tabela junto.


essa sintaxe do inner join é válida? {$this->sellerID}. Se puder explicar melhor.

Eu gostaria de saber como que você chegou a essas conclusões WHERE produto.seller_id = {$this->sellerID}, ON produto.id = item.id_produto e ORDER BY produto.qtd_vendido? Conteúdo gerado por ChatGPT e similares não é permitido no Stack Overflow em português.

Era bem isso que eu estava procurando. Obrigado pela ajuda!
